# Is there a cleaner way to read in mulipt *.csv files and add a column then a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to read in several *.csv files from disk into one big dataframe including a new column of paths as a string in an efficient and clean way.
Is there a way other then a for-loop?

Data are stored in the same form for different realizations. The setup is the same except the realizations have varying parameter values (and thus results) but are always store via `pd.to_csv()` with the same columns.

Current solution via for loop:

```
dfs = []

for path in paths:
    df = pd.read_csv(path)
    df['PATH'] = path
    dfs.append(df)

concated_dfs = pd.concat(dfs)
```

List comprehension but missing column of file paths

```
concated_dfs = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(path) for path in paths])
```

Desired result: A concated dataframe including a columns describing the path or realization.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your `for` loop. Don't chase list comprehensions for the sake of it.

Comment: Thank you. I got curious if there is another way.

Comment: It is clean. Now possibly for performance: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76834090/12846804